# Show close option in Google Chrome kiosk mode / view

Tags: google-chrome

I have launched  google chrome in kiosk mode from my windows desktop application

using

```
chrome.exe –kiosk http://www.my.url.com
```

I want to show the CLOSE option/button in kiosk mode.

Note that I do not have keyboard available to exit.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's Chrome, you can simply use Javascript:

```
<a href="javascript: window.close()">Close</a>
```

Comment: Yes! window.lose() cannot work in normal mode, but work in kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Close Kiosk Chrome extension located here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-kiosk/dfbjahmenldfpkokepmfmkjkhdjelmkb?hl=en

This does not actually show the close button, but it allows you to close it from within your code.

After you install the extension and when the application is running in kiosk mode inside Chrome, your JavaScript code should change the location URL as follows:

document.location.href = "http://closekiosk";

This is a trigger to the extension to close kiosk mode.

Comment: That link is broken.  This looks similar though: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/exit-kiosk/oickijkfojmeggjbbhajnpjapbkippen?hl=en-GB

Comment: Whats the resion behind using this extenstion if we have to program our application to change location, while op can just use window.close(); if he want to reprogramm his application. Actually he want to achieve this by chrome flag aur command lines.