# How to close Chrome running in Kiosk mode programmatically?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome, kiosk

I have an Angular 9 app running in Chrome which itself is running in Kiosk mode. I need an option to close Chrome since there is no keyboard attached to the PC where the app is running.

Is there a way to do this programmatically without using an extenstion? A switch to another browser is possible.

<s>I tried to get the `window` object in Angular and call `window.close();` but it seems as if I didn't get the right one and only a component of the app closed instead of the chrome window.</s>

I know that you can't close a window that wasn't opened with JavaScript but going off the comment on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507074/8183483) I thought that Kiosk mode might be different.

#### Edit:

The component closing happened because of a bug in our own software and `window.close();` doesn't work which is the expected behaviour.

Comment: What kind of Kiosk mode are you using? Kiosk-mode for Chrome Apps is different to Kiosk-mode on ChromeOS (Chromebooks) - which is (again) different to using `--kiosk` on Windows (and then you could also run Chrome normally but within [Windows' own kiosk-mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app)).

Comment: @Dai I'm running Chrome on Windows 10 with the `--kiosk` flag.

Comment: Are you allowed to write/run another application on the kiosk beside the browser?

Comment: @JavierAlegria Yes, that would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a watchdog process that will:

- Launch the browser
- Monitor the window title

If the window title changes to something like 'TERMINATING - Chrome', which is something you can change from within JavaScript, the watchdog process can kill the browser process.

The watchdog could also restart the browser if it crashes on its own without requesting termination.